# How To Send Firebase Push Notification from one app to another app connect to same project

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-layout, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-web

How To Send Firebase Push Notification from one app to another app connect to same project

I have Used http to send notification to specific device using token but i am unable to send to another app

I have Two App with Same Firebase project

One is Admin And Other is client
I want to send push notification from client app to Admin is this possible if yes than how.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem: when you have two apps installed on a single device they should each be getting a different FCM token, regardless of whether they part of the same Firebase project. Is that not happening for you?

Comment: Try sending notification from postman using FCM tokken Id.
Also put logs in receiver that whether logs appears on notification receival or not. I hope this will sort of help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have two apps installed on a single device, each of them will have a different FCM token, regardless of whether they part of the same Firebase project. So you can send a message to a specific app by sending it to the token for that app.